# cypher path with condition on relationship direction

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to find all paths given a start node

```
MATCH path=(n)-[rels*1..10]-(m)
```

with the following 2 conditions on path inlcusion:

1. true if relationship between subsequent nodes in path has property PROP='true'
2. if `type(relationship)=SENDS` then true if direction of the relationship is outgoing (from one path node to the next node in the path)

Another way of phrasing this is that direction doesn't matter unless the relationship name is SENDS

I can do condition 1 with `WHERE ALL (r IN rels WHERE r.PROP='true')` however ive no idea how to do condition 2.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand, but can't you just declare type and direction in the pattern? I.e. `MATCH path=(n)-[rels:SENDS*1..10]->(m)`

Comment: No, I dont think so, only some of the relationships are 'SENDS'  So to maybe explain better... I want to path to cross relations where PROP='true', and direction is either way, however when there is a SENDS encountered I need to also check the direction because for SENDS I only allow outgoing direction in the path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I can think of to filter on relationship direction without declaring direction in the match pattern is by comparing the start node of each relationship in the path with the node at the corresponding index of the `nodes()` collection from the path. For this you need the relationship and node collections from the path, an index counter and some boolean evaluation equivalent to `ALL()`. One way to do it is to use `REDUCE` with a collection for the accumulator, so you can accumulate index and maintain a true/false value for the path at the same time. Here's an example, the accumulator starts at `[0,1]` where the `0` is the index for testing that `startNode(r)` equals the node at the corresponding index in the node collection (i.e. it's an outgoing relationship) and the `1` represents `true`, which signifies that the path has not yet failed your conditions. For each relationship the index value is incremented and the `CASE/WHEN` clause multiplies the 'boolean' with 1 if your conditions are satisfied, with 0 if not. The evaluation of the path is then the evaluation of the second value in the collection returned by `REDUCE` -- if 1 then yay, if 0 then boo.

```
MATCH path = (n)-[*1..10]-(m)
WITH path, nodes(path) as ns, relationships(path) as rs
WHERE REDUCE(acc = [0,1], r IN rs |
    [acc[0]+1, CASE WHEN 
        r.PROP='true' AND
        (type(r) <> "SENDS" OR startNode(r) = ns[acc[0]]) THEN acc[1]*1 ELSE acc[1]*0 END]
)[1] = 1
RETURN path
```

or maybe this is more readable

```
WHERE REDUCE(acc = [0,1], r IN rs |
    CASE WHEN 
        r.PROP=true AND
        (type(r) <> "SENDS" OR startNode(r) = ns[acc[0]]) 
        THEN [acc[0]+1, acc[1]*1]
        ELSE [acc[0]+1, acc[1]*0]
    END
)[1] = 1
```

Here's a console: http://console.neo4j.org/?id=v3kgz9

Comment: Thank you.  This is correct.  I was nearly there with a solution that did not use reduce or an accumulator.  My problem is that I didn't I could pass on multiple collections from the WITH.  I used this knowledge to fix my approach which turned out also correct but slower.  MATCH p=(n)-[rels*1..10]-(m) WHERE   ALL (r IN rels WHERE r.TRAVERSABLE='true')        WITH p, range(0,length(p)-1) AS idx, nodes(p) as ns, relationships(p) as rs      WHERE ALL (i in idx           WHERE CASE type(rs[i])='a' WHEN TRUE THEN startnode(rs[i])=ns[i] ELSE TRUE  END )  RETURN nodes(p);

Comment: Oooh this pattern takes a long time to run on my use case!

Answer (score 0):

For completeness I've answered the question using jjaderberg correct solution plus a condition to fix the start node and ensure that no zero length paths are included

```
MATCH p = (n)-[*1..10]-(m) 
WHERE ALL(n in nodes(p) WHERE 1=length(filter(m in nodes(p) WHERE m=n)))  
    AND (id(n)=1) 
WITH p, nodes(p) as ns, relationships(p) as rs 
WHERE REDUCE(acc = [0,1], r IN rs | [acc[0]+1, 
    CASE WHEN r.PROP='true' AND (type(r) <> "SEND" OR startNode(r) = ns[acc[0]]) 
    THEN acc[1]*1 
    ELSE acc[1]*0
    END])[1] = 1 
RETURN nodes(p);
```

Or my alternative answer based on jjaderbags answer but does not use accumulator but which is slightly slower

```
   MATCH p=(n)-[rels*1..10]-(m) 
WHERE ALL(n in nodes(p) WHERE 1=length(filter(m in nodes(p) WHERE m=n)))  
    AND(  ALL (r IN rels WHERE r.PROP='true')  
    AND id(n)=1)        
WITH p, range(0,length(p)-1) AS idx, nodes(p) as ns, relationships(p) as rs      
WHERE ALL (i in idx WHERE 
    CASE type(rs[i])='SEND' 
    WHEN TRUE THEN startnode(rs[i])=ns[i] 
    ELSE TRUE 
    END)  
RETURN nodes(p);
```